# How to use Xcode debugger while iOS device is connected to an accessory?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, debugging

iOS devices can only be connected to one other device (PC or accessory) at once. I am currently developing a MFI accessory, and I can't access the debugger while working on the accessory because the iPhone is already connected to the accessory. Does anyone have any experience with such a problem? It is really hard to debug without the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

As of Xcode 9 and iOS 11, remote debugging is supported. You can run and debug an app from Xcode with any pre-configured device on your network. Choose "Connect via network" in the Devices and Simulators window and it should work.

See [How do you perform wireless debugging in Xcode 9 with iOS 11, Apple TV 4K, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382841/how-do-you-perform-wireless-debugging-in-xcode-9-with-ios-11-apple-tv-4k-etc) for details.

Comment: And, it might be added, this feature is explicitly touted by Apple as solving _exactly_ the problem the OP posed.